# Error when use callBy on a function with default parameters in Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I try to call a function with default parameters values without put parameters in Kotlin.

For example:

```
class Test {
    fun callMeWithoutParams(value : Double = 0.5) = value * 0.5

    fun callIt(name: String) = this.javaClass.kotlin
            .members.first { it.name == name }
            .callBy(emptyMap())
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   println(Test().callIt("callMeWithoutParams"))
}
```

I have the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No argument provided for a required parameter: instance of fun 
 Test.callMeWithoutParams(kotlin.Double): kotlin.Double
     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod(KCallableImpl.kt:139)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:111)
    at Test.callIt(Main.kt:15)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:20)
```

Strange because the parameter is not required but optional...

Comment: Unrelated, but `this.javaClass.kotlin` seems a bit roundabout over `this::class`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a bit of testing, a `KClass` won't keep track of the actual object it was created from, the main difference being that `this::class` will use the runtime type of `this`.

You can verify this by querying information about all the parameters:

```
 name | isOptional | index |     kind |          type
-----------------------------------------------------
 null        false       0   INSTANCE            Test
value         true       1      VALUE   kotlin.Double
```

The first parameter is actually the instance of the class. Using `this::callMeWithoutParams` will keep track of `this`, removing the first row of the table, but naturally doesn't allow for finding the member by name. You can still call the method by providing the object:

```
fun callIt(name: String) { 
    val member = this::class.members.first { it.name == name }
    member.callBy(mapOf(member.instanceParameter!! to this))
}
```