# How to call Kotlin companion factory method using callBy()?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-companion

I have code accepts a class as a parameter and prepares data to call either the constructor for that class of a companion object factory method if the factory method is present.

All works fine when calling the constructor, but I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No argument provided for a required parameter: instance of fun nz.salect.objjson.JVMTest.StudentWithFactory.Companion.fromJson(kotlin.String, kotlin.Int): nz.salect.objjson.JVMTest.StudentWithFactory
```

when calling the factory method.  The factory method in question:

```
data class StudentWithFactory(val name: String, val years: Int=0) {

    companion object {

        fun fromJson(name: String="", age: Int = 0):StudentWithFactory {
            return StudentWithFactory(name, age)
        }
    }
}
```

has no required parameters, unless there is some hidden parameter.  Any ideas?

In fact, I reverted removing the parameters completely from `fromJson` and directly calling the companion method using `::fromJson.callby(emptyMap())`.  Same error.

It is clear that companion methods need at least one additional parameter.  Perhaps the class?  Or the companion object?
How can I specify the needed parameter(s)?

The function building up the callBy() is supplied a class (or finds the class from a supplied class) and json names and values.

```
var funk:KFunction<*>?=null
val companionFuncs=cls.companionObject?.declaredMemberFunctions
if(companionFuncs?.size ?:0 >0){
    companionFuncs?.forEach {
        if(it.name == "fromJson") funk=it
    }

}
val cons:KFunction<T> = if(funk != null)
       funk as KFunction<T>
    else
       cls.primaryConstructor ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("no primary constructor ${cls.simpleName}")
val valuesMap = cons.parameters.filter{it.name in vals}
    .associateBy(
    {it},
    {generateValue(it)}
)
val data = cons.callBy(valuesMap) //as T
return data
```

Comment: Please provide your code that invokes the factory method. I assume you use reflection, then the default parameters will not be used.

Comment: I'm not a kotlin reflection expert, but maybe you'll need `@JvmOverloads` on your companion factory method, so that the no-arg method actualy exists in the bytecode.

Comment: Can you provide the code which you call factory method in? I tryied to call the factory method directly without problems, but maybe I "misunderstood your problem...

Comment: I think this is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175768/error-when-use-callby-on-a-function-with-default-parameters-in-kotlin

Comment: @Rene I added the code that invokes the factory method. Default parameters are used where present in supplied json data.

Comment: @Joffrey, using a annotation to make the factory method a true static is an interesting idea and i will explore, but JvmOverloads does not change the need for the companion object as a parameter :(

Comment: @PietroMartinelli i posted the relevant source. Hope that helps convey the problem. It can be a challenge to make things clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parameters` property to determine how much parameters you have to pass to the function/constructor.

If you call

```
val paramsConstr = StudentWithFactory::class.primaryConstructor?.parameters
```

`paramsConstr` will be of size two as expected, but if you call

```
val paramsFunc = ::fromJson.parameters
```

`paramsFunc` will be of size three. The first element corresponds to the instance of the companion object. So, thats the list of parameters you need to provide.

You can invoke the `fromJson` like this:

```
// not using any default parameters
::fromJson.callBy(mapOf(
        paramsFunc[0] to StudentWithFactory::class.companionObjectInstance,
        paramsFunc[1] to "Hello",
        paramsFunc[2] to 30
))

// using only the default parameter for "name"
::fromJson.callBy(mapOf(
        paramsFunc[0] to StudentWithFactory::class.companionObjectInstance,
        paramsFunc[2] to 30
))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54836206/1788806), a more technical explanation:

Yes, there actually is a hidden parameter and you can see it (for example), if you take a look at the decompiled (to Java) bytecode:

```
public final class StudentWithFactory {

   // ...
   public static final class Companion {
      // ...
      @NotNull
      public static StudentWithFactory fromJson$default(StudentWithFactory.Companion var0, String var1, int var2, int var3, Object var4) {
         // ...

         return var0.fromJson(var1, var2);
      }
      // ...
   }
}
```

The first parameter (`var0`) is actually an instance of the companion object. `var1` (name) and `var2` (age) are the parameters you declared. `var3` is a bitmask for determining if explicit values have been passed or if the default ones should be used*. I honestly don't know what `var4` is for. It is unused in the Java code. But the imported part is that you only need to worry about `var0`, `var1` and `var2` if you want to invoke the function.

So, in the end the non-static version of fromJson* is actually invoked on the instance of the companion object:

```
var0.fromJson(var1, var2)
```

<sub>*left code out for simplicity</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Willi, I posted my question late Friday night for me, and was thinking about an experiment similar to that and using the reflection data in the debugger to verify that the companion object is the hidden parameter.   As the data passed to the method making the call is the Class, from which the companion object is found by reflection, then the fromJson() method found from the companion object, the question now is what value to pass, and i will update the question

Comment: @innov8 you can find a working example for your original question in my other answer.

Comment: @innov8 such big edits are discouraged because they render already given answers (to the original question) obsolete. My answers fully covered your original question. Now they don't. Pls create a new question for that and rollback the edit.

Comment: The edit added the code, as several people asked for it.  The code made a 'big' edit, but as it is only adding code people asked for, it clarifies the question.  I did also then add text moving on to a follow on question.  That I have removed and will post as a separate question.  I would like to highlight your answer as a correct answer for reference, but suggest adding a comment that constructors are unusual in not having hidden parameters

Comment: @innov8 ok, i see! "but suggest adding a comment that constructors are unusual in not having hidden parameters" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Part of the puzzle was that the code worked fine for calling a constructor, but the same code would not call the factory method.  To me, a key in putting the picture together is what while constructors do NOT have a hidden parameter, companion object methods do. I think mentioning something about this in the answer could play a big part in helping others :)    Thank you for your input, it is appreciated that you take the time.

Comment: @innov8 I added that in my short answer, since it is more practical. this long answer is, as i said, an addition to that :)